# Raspberry Pi VGA cable not showing, accessories not lighting up

Tags: displays

I have the following setup:

1. Raspberry Pi Zero 2W
2. MiniHDMI to HDMI adapter
3. HDMI to VGA cable
4. Monitor with VGA input

Nothing shows up on the monitor, and USB accessories don't light up.

I can tell that the monitor is receiving signal, because normally it shows a "No VGA signal" message. Now, it simply enters Power Save Mode immediately after booting up.

---

Why does it not work?

I flashed the drive using the Raspberry Pi flasher with a compatible image

I searched the internet for a solution, but did not find someone with the same problem

I pressed buttons on the keyboard, but the keyboard didn't even light up

---

I asked on Stack Overflow and it got closed for off-topic, please tell me if there’s a better Stack Exchange for this.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI is digital and VGA is analog.  So, a passive cable cannot convert one to the other.

Some cables have electronics powered by the HDMI in the connector.  I suspect that the Pi is unable to power the electronics.

A cable like this can get its power from the Micro-USB plug

[image]

This is the description for it

> Dynamix C-HDMIVGA-2M 2m HDMI to VGA Cable, Includes Micro USB Female Optional Power - No HDCP - DMI 1.4 Max Res: 1080p60Hz (1920x1080) - Directional cable